# Finding dimension of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W$ a subspace of $V$. Let $q : V\to V/W$ be
defined by $q(v) = v + W$ for $v\in V$.

a) Prove that $q : V\to V/W$ is a linear transformation which is onto
and show that $N(q) = W$.

b) Suppose that $V$ is finite dimensional. Use a) and the dimension theorem to derive a formula relating $\dim(V)$, $\dim(W)$, and $\dim(V/W)$.

c) Alternatively, let $\{w_1,\ldots, w_k\}$ be a basis for $W$. and let $\{w_1,\ldots, w_k, v_1,\ldots, v_{n−k}\}$
be a basis for $V$ extended from the basis for $W$. Show that
$\{v_1 +W,\ldots, v_{n−k} +W\}$ is a basis for $V/W$.

For a), I proved it with:

$q : V\to V/W$, $q(v) = v + W$ for $v\in V$. Suppose $u,v\in V$ and $c\in\Bbb R$.

$q(u + v)= (u + v) + W = (u + W ) + (v + W) = q(u) + q(v)$

$q(cv) = cv + W = c(v + W) = cq(v)$

So all elements $v + W$ in $V/W$ we have $q(v)= v + W$. Therefore it's onto.

$q(v) = v + W = 0 + W$ so $v - 0 = v\in W$.
Therefore $N(q) = W$.

For b) I tried to prove it with:

If $q$ is onto, then $R(T) = V/W$ also $N(q) = W$.

So we have $\dim(V) = \dim(V/W) + \dim(W)$ by the dimension theorem.

Does my proof make sense? Also, I'm not sure how to prove c). Any input would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't show that $N(q) = W$

Comment: sorry, I forgot to type in that part.

Answer (score 1):

Not only makes sense: up to the point you did, your proof is correct and nice: at the end, you already proved that $\;\dim V/W = \dim V-\dim W\;$

For (c) you can try the following: let $\;a_1,...,a_{n-k}\in F=$ the definition field, be such that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}a_i(v_i+W)=\overline0 \;(=\text{the zero element in}\;\;\;V/W)=W\implies$$

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}a_iv_i\right)+W=\overline0\iff\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}a_iv_i\in W\implies$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}a_iv_i=\sum_{j=1}^nb_jw_j\;,\;\;\text{for some scalars}\;\;b_j\in F\implies$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}a_iv_i-\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_jw_j=0$$

but $\;\{w_i\,,\,v_j\}\;$ is a **basis**, so...complete the proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for c:** Note that every $v \in V$ can be written as 
$v = \sum_{i=1}^ka_i w_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i v_i$.
Show that
$$
q\left(\sum_{i=1}^k a_i w_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i v_i\right) = 
\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i v_i + W
$$
Because $q$ is onto, the $v_i$ span the set $V/W$.  Also, $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i v_i + W = 0 + W$ implies that all $b_i$ are $0$, so the set is linearly independent.  Thus, the vectors $v_i + W$ form a basis of $V/W$.